# Polynomial roots problem

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $P\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is a polynomial such that

$$P(x) = x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$

and $P(-1) = 0$. Further suppose that the other two roots $x_1, x_2$ of $P$ satisfy $x_1 + x_2 = 5$. If the remainder of the division of $P$ by $x+2$ is $P(0)$, what is $a+b+c$?

$P$ should have the following factorization:

$$P(x) = \alpha(x+1)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\quad\space x_1+x_2 = 5, \alpha\in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$$

For $x =-2$ and $x = 0$,

$$P(-2)  = \alpha(-1)(-2-x_1)(-2-x_2) = -\alpha(2+x_1)(2+x_2)\tag{1}$$

$$P(0)  = \alpha(-x_1)(-x_2) = \alpha x_1 x_2\tag{2}$$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, and using $x_1+x_2 = 5$ doesn't lead me to a nice solution for $x_1, x_2$. Which I thought it should in this problem

Comment: You should be able to determine $P(1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations are correct, though your constant $\alpha$ is unnecessary since $P(x)$ is monic (the coefficient of $x^3$ is $1$), so we must have $\alpha = 1$. Now, equating gives $$\begin{align*}-\left(2+x_1\right)\left(2+x_2\right) = x_1x_2 &\iff -4-2\left(x_1+x_2\right)-x_1x_2 = x_1x_2 \\ &\iff x_1x_2 = -2-\left(x_1+x_2\right) \\ &\iff x_1x_2 = -2-5 = -7,\end{align*}$$ so $$\begin{align*}a+b+c &= P(1)-1 \\ &= 2\left(1-x_1\right)\left(1-x_2\right)-1 \\ &= 2\left(1-\left(x_1+x_2\right)+x_1x_2\right)-1 \\ &= 1-2 \cdot 5 + 2\cdot (-7) \\ &= -23.\end{align*}$$